# Accept USDT (Tether) for payment method in website

Tags: payments, usdt, tether

Is it able to use Binance API to accept USDT as a payment method on the website?
For this purpose we need can generate a unique USDT address per order and can track it. If Binance is not a good solution what is the best solution for this.
We need to create 3 types of addresses ( TRC20, ERC20, Omni).

Answer (score 1):

I am personally not recommending Binance API, because it opens your wallet completely to you system. It means your Binance wallet can be accessible from you system. Any hack in your system can cause complete loss of your all Binance wallet's crypto. We are using coinremitter Payment processor for this types of situation. They offer ETH, USDT OMNI, BTC as well. It minimize risk and improve security. They provides auto withdraw functionalities. So, When someone send crypto to your coinremitter's wallet they forwarded those money to your secure wallet. in this way, It never gets steal.

You can take a look at coinremitter first. It will gives you extra level of security.
https://coinremitter.com/docs

Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [bitpay](https://bitpay.com/) to implement cryptocurrency payments including Tether. Or coinbase commerce. I've used both and they are excellent.

Alternatively you could ask people to send you Tether directly to your Ethereum address and check the payments manually to deliver your product or service.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it for your own website, it will be a difficult process to follow all these networks (trc20, erc20, omni) and receive incoming payments. There are many crypto payment gateway companies that do this job, it would be much easier for you to use one of them payid19,bitpay,coinbase,coinpayments etc.
I recommend https://payid19.com it has an basic api and no kyc.